# How to configure Nutch to avoid crawling nonsense calendar webpage

Tags: calendar, nutch

I am using Nutch to index a website. I notice that Nutch has crawled some junk webpages, such as http://**************/category/events/2015-11. This webpage is about the event occurring in 2015, 11. This is completely nonsense for me. I want to know is it possible for Nutch to intelligently skip such webpages. It may be argued that I can use Regex to avoid this. However, as the naming pattern of calendar webpages are not the same all the time, there is no way to write a perfect Regex for this. I know Heritrix (a Internet archive crawler) has such capabilities to avoid crawling nonsense calendar webpage. Does anyone solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way apart from regex url filtering that can do this. You can keep adding new patterns to the regex file whenever you see an undesired page makes it through the crawled content.

Comment: So it seems there is no intelligent way to do this.